# delay display of jquery sortable placeholder

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a sortable table using jqueryUI sortable and i have sildeUp and down delays for the sorting so it looks smooth.

But i also have the placeholder element styled with a dashed border so the user knows where the element will be dropped.

The problem is upon draggin an element the dashed placeholders height gets animated all the time and it looks really ugly.

Basically i want the dashed element to be invisible until the point where there is enough room for it, then show it. Right now it gets animated from 0 height to full height. It would be better if it appeared in full height once there is enough room for it.

How can i delay it? I am setting the border using css() but dont know how to tell it to wait.

Here my code

http://jsbin.com/ucopun/122/edit

```
$("#myTable tbody").sortable({
    helper: fixhelper,
    revert: 300,
    placeholder: 'ui-placeholder',
        'start': function (event, ui) {
          ui.placeholder.html('<td class="uisort" colspan="3"></td>').slideUp(200);
          ui.placeholder.children("td").css({'border': 'dashed 2px black'});
        },
        change: function (e,ui){
      $(ui.placeholder).hide().slideDown(200);
    }



  });
  $("#myTable tbody").on('sortstart',  function(event, ui) {
    $("td").css({'background-color': '#313131'});
 $(ui.item).children("td").css({'background-color': '#fff'});
  });
  $("#myTable tbody").on('mouseup',  function(event, ui) {
 $("td").css({'background-color': '#fff'});
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U need to reduce the animation time so that it wont look 'ugly'.

try reducing ur slideUp and slideDown animation time to '1'.

Let me know if that works for you.